# How to write a ConvertString function

Tags: c++

I am studying C++ and I am supposed to write a function (ConvertString) that modifies the input string input_string by
substitutes each alphabetical character by a character, which is mod_int positions down the alphabet. For example, if

input_string: `Hello` 
mod_int: `4`
mod_string: `Lipps` //L = H+4, i=e+4, etc.

Can someone help me out please?
Thank you!

```
int x;
x = input_string.length();
for (int i=0; i<input_string.length(); i++)
    if (isalpha(input_string[x]))
    {
        int start = 65;
        if (islower(input_string[x]))
            int start = 97;
        return ConvertString(input_string, mod_int =
                (((int)input_string[x] - start + mod_int) % 26) + start);
    } else cout << input_string[x];
```

Comment: Just curious, what would happen with the letter "Z"? Would it go into a symbol or wrap back around the alphabet to "c"

Comment: ‘z’ should be substituted by ‘a’

Comment: This site works better if you show us what you have tried and explain why and how it fails and where you need help.

Comment: Alright sounds good ill post what ive been trying!

Comment: Crack out the textbook and read the bit on writing functions again because you're missing a few important points that are (hopefully) better covered there than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with a storing your input in a `std::string`. Then, consider using [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to transform using your function. I will give you an example with `toupper()` function, which you should replace with the function you are required to write (and pass pointer to that function instead of `toupper()`):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 

std::string input_string = "Hello"; 
std::transform(input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), data.begin(), ::toupper);
```

**EDIT:** Your function should have the following signature: `int convert_char(char c);`.

Comment: so basically i replace toupper by  the ConvertString function that i made?

Comment: Yes. Remember that the function should take a single `char` as an argument.

Comment: what do you mean by that? I understand what char is but im not sure i get what u mean by taking a single char as your argument...

Comment: what do you think of the program i wrote so far? does it make sense? im trying make it recognize if its an upper or lower case letter.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a signature of the function you need to write. If you ConvertString is going to operate on an ASCII string, you don't need to check if the character is upper or lowercase.

Comment: how do you accept an answer? sorry im new to this :/

Comment: Just write: `std::transform(input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), data.begin(), convert_char);`

Comment: Why does it say that C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations when i put:  std::transform(input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), data.begin(), convert_char);